# Why is Javascript 'every' function returning false?

Tags: javascript

I have a quick question on why my function is returning false, when I expect it to be returning true. I have looked at the documentation for Array.prototype.every, and I still can't seem to find it. Thanks for your help in advance.

For some context, this is part of a coderbyte question called arithGeo. The current function I am working on here is supposed to return true if the difference between each element is the same. Here, I expect this to return true, since each element is 5 apart from the next.

Here is my function

```
var arr = [5, 10, 15];
function isArith(arr){
    var diff = arr[1] - arr[0];
    return arr.every(function(val, ind, col){
      // if statement checks to make sure I stay in bounds.
      if(col[ind + 1] !== undefined){
         var next = col[ind + 1] - val;
         console.log(diff === next   );
         // logging shows the following statement to be true, for every iteration
         return diff === next; 
      }
    });
}


var arith = isArith(arr);
console.log('arith: ', arith) // logs false
```

Comment: A better test might be `if (ind < arr.length - 1)` so the last members you test are the second last and last ones. Do you have to accommodate sparse arrays?

Comment: No, I don't have to accommodate sparse arrays. I think your suggestion is clearer than `col[ind + 1] !== undefined`. Will implement, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the last iteration you'll return `undefined`, which will be interpreted as `false`. The code does that because if the `if` fails (which it does on the last element) there's no `return` statement. If you add `return true` to the end after the `if` it should work.

Comment: Unless some intermediate value is *undefined* or the array is sparse.

Answer (score 2):

When you reach the last element, you test to see if there is a next element so you don't compare the last element with nothing. That's great. But in that case, you forget to `return` anything, and the default `return` is `undefined`, which is falsy. Just put in `else return true`.